# Issue with while loop

Tags: c++, arduino, telegram, telegram-bot, esp8266

For my project I am trying to messure the distance between my sensor and an object to trigger an alarm. If the alarm goes off, a message will be sent to my Telegram account with a library (UniversalTelegramBot). For messuring th distance, I'm using a loop to the distance between the sensor and the object, but to check if I get any messages through I also need to use a loop. I want to make it so that with the comment "/off" the distance get messured again, but when you type something else it waits till the comment "/off" gets used again. While the alarm is on and it's checking for messages, I want to use "/start" as comment to see which other comments to use and how to use it, without going to the messure loop again.

My main problem is that when the alarm goes off and I type anything, it doesn't matter what, the loop starts messuring again, but I only want it to go back to messuring when I type "/off" in telegram.

My code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>

UniversalTelegramBot bot(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN, client);

int delayBetweenChecks = 250;
unsigned long lastTimeChecked;

void handleNewMessages(int numNewMessages) {

  for (int i = 0; i < numNewMessages; i++) {
    String chat_id = String(bot.messages[i].chat_id);
    String text = bot.messages[i].text;

    String from_name = bot.messages[i].from_name;
    if (from_name == "")
      from_name = "Gast";

    Serial.print("De volgende knop is ingedrukt: ");
    Serial.println(text);

    if (text == F("/off")) {
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
      alarmStatus = 0;
      noTone(buzzer);
    }

    if (text == "/start") {
      String welcome = "Welkom bij jouw alarmsysteem, " + from_name + ".\n";
      welcome += "/off : om het alarm uit te zetten\n";
      bot.sendMessage(chat_id, welcome, "Markdown");
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // Convert the time into a distance
  cm = (duration / 2) / 29.1;   // Divide by 29.1 or multiply by 0.0343
  inches = (duration / 2) / 74; // Divide by 74 or multiply by 0.0135

  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();
  while (cm <= 9) {
    Serial.println("ALARM!");
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    tone(buzzer, 250);
    alarmStatus = 1;
    if (alarmStatus = 1) {
      if (millis() > lastTimeChecked + delayBetweenChecks) {
        int numNewMessages = bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1);
        handleNewMess ages(numNewMessages);
        if (numNewMessages) {
          Serial.println("got response");
          handleNewMessages(numNewMessages);
        }
        lastTimeChecked = millis();
      }
    }
    break;
  }
  delay(250);
}
```

Comment: `alarmStatus = 1;
        if (alarmStatus == 1) `  seems weird ?

Comment: Do you receive  `/off` in your program? If you do get the `/off` message, won't it just restart the alarm (since `cm` is still `<= 9`)?

Comment: @Clonk I made that so that when I type "/off" the alarmStatus goes to 0 and it leaves the if/while

Comment: @TedLyngmo I receive the /off in my program, so that works fine. But when I type another comment / text in Telegram, it also checks the distance again since there was a message received.

Comment: "_when I type "/off" the alarmStatus goes to 0 and it leaves the if/while_" - How? `cm` is still `<= 9`, isn't it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, only it's just a demo, I made it so when a door opens it gets noticed by the sensor, so it'll only go to 9 cm once, after that the door is open/closed and the distance is higher than 9 cm

Comment: I'm looking at the code in your question which you are using as a [mcve].

Comment: @TedLyngmo Edited now so I think it's still possible to understand the code easily, but there's a lot of code which is important I guess.

Comment: I think I was reading it wrong because of the indentation you have in your code. Please try to indent it properly so it becomes easier to read in the future. I did it for you this time.

Comment: Why `while (cm <= 9)` instead of `if (cm <= 9)`? You always `break` out of the `while`, which makes it an `if` anyway.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I noticed that, thanks for it. Will do that.
I was just trying out how I could get it to work so it wouldn't leave the if statement before the alarmStatus would be be at 0.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you could keep two separate state variables. One for turning the alarm on and off when you leave/return home and one for when triggering the alarm.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>

const int delayBetweenChecks = 250;

bool alarmStatus = false;    // off by default
bool alarmTriggered = false; // off by default

UniversalTelegramBot bot(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN, client);

double measure_distance_in_cm() {
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  unsigned long duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // Convert the time into a distance
  return static_cast<double>(duration) / (29.1 * 2.);
}

void trigger_on() {
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
  alarmTriggered = true;
}

void trigger_off() {
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  alarmTriggered = false;
}

void handleNewMessages() {
  int numNewMessages = bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < numNewMessages; i++) {
    String text = bot.messages[i].text;

    Serial.println(text);

    if (text == "/start") {     // when you're leaving home
      alarmStatus = true;
      trigger_off();
    }
    else if (text == "/stop") { // when you're returning home
      alarmStatus = false;
      trigger_off();
    }
    else if (text == "/off") {  // turn off a triggered alarm
      trigger_off();
    }
    else if (test == "/on") {   // force triggering of the alarm
      trigger_on();            
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned long lastTimeChecked = millis();

  handleNewMessages();

  if(alarmStatus) {                // you only need to do this if the alarm is on
    if(alarmTriggered == false) {  // only measure if the alarm isn't already triggered  
      double cm = measure_distance_in_cm();
      if(cm <= 9.) {
        Serial.println("ALARM!");
        trigger_on();
      }
    }
    // If it's triggered: Sound the alarm in 200ms bursts until /off or /stop is received 
    if(alarmTriggered) tone(buzzer, delayBetweenChecks-50);
  }

  // try to keep the polling at a steady pace
  lastTimeChecked += delayBetweenChecks;
  unsigned long now = millis();
  if(lastTimeChecked > now) delay(lastTimeChecked - now);
}
```

Disclaimer: I don't have an Arduino so I can't test it myself.